# Misdeal Texas Holdem

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

In Texas Holdem the hole cards have been dealt out. One person has only one card. Is this a misdeal? The other scenario one person received no cards is this a misdeal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be a dead hand, or a misdeal. Generally speaking if there is no action, it is a misdeal. If there is action it is a dead hand. of course rules vary.